# In cocoa (or generally in objective C) is there a way to send a message to objects in another process?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, message

Let's say I have two Cocoa apps running on the same machine (OSX). Is there a way to send "objective c" messages from one to objects in the other one?
These two apps need to remain independent, so they can be started and stopped by the user independently or users can have only one of the two on their machines. I know the best solution maybe using Sockets or pipes, but I wanted to know if I am not instantiating an object is there a way to send it a message (or call its methods) in anyway? I understand that the receiver may just ignore the messages or does whatever it wants with them.

Comment: Be aware that if you plan on submitting your app to the app store that the new sandboxing requirements will prevent an app in a sandbox from using inter-process communication with any apps outside the sandbox. Both apps need to be in the same sandbox for IPC to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is distributed objects. It allows you to broadcast an object from one application or thread so that other applications or threads can find it and communicate with it. Each application or thread using it will create a proxy object which it can send messages to, and those messages are forwarded to the actual object. Unfortunately, Apple seems to have removed its guide for distributed objects, but here is a [GNUstep tutorial](http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/DistributedObjects/) as well as the [GNUstep manual](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_7.html) to help you out. You will also want to look at the [NSConnection class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: So if I haven't planed it in advance in the first app, there is no way I can do it other than updating the first (receiver app)? I mean there is no way without a redesign of the receiver to do this?

Comment: @Ali You don't really need to redesign. You just need to add code which gets the proxy before you use it. But yes, you will have to make some modifications.

Comment: There is an "Introduction to Distributed Objects" in the documentation in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

`NSDistributedNotification`+`NSDistributedNotificationCenter` is another option. it is similar to `NSNotification`+`NSNotificationCenter`. with it, you are restricted to plist types.

Comment: There is no `NSDistributedNotification`. NSDistributedNotificationCenter uses the same NSNotification class that NSNotificationCenter uses. More to the point, NSDistributedNotificationCenter is more for broadcast than for communication between two specific applications.